# how to pass a map of map in request spring boot request body?

Tags: spring-boot, request

I have a request which looks like this .

```json
"logRequest": {
    "ObIdentifier": "B2003001A22A10A52323J02279",
    "notes": "Company Code could not be determined"
  }
```

How do I get the parameter in the request body for this? I want to pass as `@RequestBody` Map(Map), is there any way I can do this?

Well, I am new to spring boot and not really understanding how to parse this JSON in a simple format. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

spring automatically handles the conversion from/to JSON objects via the `@RequestBody` annotation

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/dummy")
    public void dummy(@RequestBody Map<String, Map<String, String>> nestedMap) {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure , thankyou very much for your reqponse , this simple implementation worked for me .